# Functions inside class and constructor don't work at all and don't return any errors

Tags: c++

TL;DR: I have the following class on an ESP32 and the functions don't work as intended:

```
class Wiegand {
  private:
    std::vector<bool> _array{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    uint8_t facilityCode = 0;
    uint16_t cardNumber = 0;
    void calculate(uint32_t decimal) {
      for (uint8_t i = 23; i >= 0; --i) {
        _array[i] = decimal & 1;
        decimal >>= 1;
      }
    }
  public:
    Wiegand(uint32_t id) {
      calculate(id);
      facilityCode = id >> 16;
      cardNumber = id & 0xffff;
    }

    std::vector<bool> getCardID() {
      return _array;
    }
    uint8_t getFacilityCode() {
      if(facilityCode == 0) {
        return 0;
      }        
      return facilityCode;
    }
    uint16_t getCardNumber() {
      if(cardNumber == 0) {
        return 0;
      }        
      return cardNumber;
    }
};
```

And the following code doesn't output a thing:

```
  Wiegand card(86840);
  std::vector<bool> cardID = card.getCardID();

  for(bool i : cardID) {
    Serial.print(i);
  }
  int foo = card.getFacilityCode();
  Serial.println(foo);
  Serial.println(card.getCardNumber());
```

Long Story:

I am trying to transform any decimal number in the range of 1 and 2^24-1 into a 24-bit binary number that I put into `cardID`.

For example: `86840` should return `000000010101001100111000`. Next I would like to take the `first 8 bits` and the `last 16 bits`, transform them in their `decimal` form and store them in other variables. Now the remaining thing to do is to take the whole binary number and add its parity bits to transform it in a 26 bit Wiegand number, following the [Wiegand protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiegand_interface).

Comment: Unrelated, but `std::vector<bool> getCardID()` -> `const std::vector<bool>& getCardID() const`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: `std::vector<bool> _array{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};` -> `std::vector<bool> _array = std::vector<bool>{24, false};`.

Comment: Is using `std::bitset` a possibility?

Comment: I meant, `const std::vector<bool>& getCardID() const {
      return _array;
    }` would avoid copy. would be const correct.

Comment: @Jarod42 `std::vector<bool> _array = std::vector<bool>{24, false};` returns `narrowing conversion of '24' from 'int' to 'bool' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]`

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica: typo on my side: `std::vector<bool>(24, false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With unsigned variable, this is infinite loop, because unsigned variable is always either zero or more:

```
for (uint8_t i = 23; i >= 0; --i)
```

Instead, use for example:

```
for (uint8_t i = 23; i + 1 > 0; --i)
```

Comment: Care to explain why ? Thank you.

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica Recommendation for OP: enable all warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` on g++ & clang++) and _treat them_.

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica as `i` is unsigned, it is always positive (`>=0`).

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica Yes

Comment: @YSC `-Wall -Wextra on g++ & clang++` I don't think that's possible in VSC.

Comment: Why do `getFacilityCode` and `getCardNumber` return 0 and respectively nothing ?

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica You have an infinite loop, so the constructor never finishes, and the line that prints is not reached.

Comment: Now, thanks to you, I don't have an infinite loop and they still output wrong.